# Deriving the results in "The Variational Gaussian Approximation Revisited (Opper and Archambeau, 2009)"

Tags: normal-distribution, variational-bayes, approximate-bayesian-computation

I am trying to derive the results in [Opper and Archambeau, 2009](https://direct.mit.edu/neco/article-abstract/21/3/786/7385/The-Variational-Gaussian-Approximation-Revisited?redirectedFrom=fulltext). In the paper, they show that the variational free energy is the following (Eq. 3.2)

$$
\mathcal{F} = \sum_n \langle -\ln \left[p(y_n|x_n) \right] \rangle_{q(x)} + \frac{1}{2}\text{Tr}(K^{-1}\Sigma) + \\
\quad \quad \quad \frac{1}{2}\mu^\top K^{-1}\mu
-\frac{1}{2} \ln |\Sigma| + \ln Z_0 - \frac{N}{2} \ln(2\pi e)
$$

based on the above they say that the optimal covariance $\Sigma$ of the variational Gaussian distribution is given by $\Sigma = (K^{-1} + \Lambda)^{-1}$ (they got this by taking derivate and setting it to zero). Here $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix that is used to parameterize the variational Gaussian distribution instead of using a full covariance matrix $\Sigma$.

But here is what I got for the solution $\Sigma$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\nabla_{\Sigma} \mathcal{F} &= \nabla_{\Sigma} (-\frac{1}{2} \ln |\Sigma| -\frac{N}{2} \ln(2\pi e) + \frac{1}{2}\text{Tr}(K^{-1}\Sigma) + \\
& \quad \quad \frac{1}{2}\mu^\top K^{-1}\mu + \sum_n \langle -\ln \left[p(y_n|x_n) \right] \rangle_{q(x)} + \ln Z_0))\\
&= -\nabla_{\Sigma} \frac{1}{2} \ln |\Sigma| + \nabla_{\Sigma} \frac{1}{2}\text{Tr}(K^{-1}\Sigma) + \nabla_{\Sigma} \sum_n \langle -\ln \left[p(y_n|x_n) \right] \rangle_{q(x)} \\
&= - \frac{1}{2} \Sigma^{-\top} + \frac{1}{2}\text{Tr}(K^{-1}\nabla_{\Sigma}\Sigma) + \sum_n \nabla_{\Sigma} \langle -\ln \left[p(y_n|x_n) \right] \rangle_{q(x)} \\
\implies \frac{1}{2} \Sigma^{-\top} &= \frac{1}{2}\text{Tr}(K^{-1}) + \sum_n \nabla_{\Sigma} \langle -\ln \left[p(y_n|x_n) \right] \rangle_{q(x)} \\
\implies \Sigma^{-\top} &= \text{Tr}(K^{-1}) + 2\sum_n \nabla_{\Sigma} \langle -\ln \left[p(y_n|x_n) \right] \rangle_{q(x)} \\
\end{aligned}
$$

The issue is the prior covariance $K$, my solution has the trace of the matrix, while the paper says it is supposed to be the full matrix $K$. Can anyone please explain how they got their results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I figured it out. I messed up $\nabla_\Sigma \frac{1}{2}\text{Tr}(K^{-1}\Sigma)$.

It is supposed to be $\frac{1}{2}\text{Tr}(\nabla_\Sigma(K^{-1}\Sigma))$, instead of $\frac{1}{2}\text{Tr}(K^{-1}\nabla_\Sigma\Sigma)$.